# Why doesn't Polymer use ES6

Tags: polymer, ecmascript-6

It seems like the React community has heavily adopted ES6 as de facto when building applications, but I realized using ES6 with Polymer is fairly uncommon and doesn't seem to be actively encouraged. I was wondering why this is and if it's considered bad "style" to develop Polymer components using ES6 and compile them down to ES5 with Babel or something?

Comment: You should ask the people who made Polymer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer and the Polymer Elements don't require transpilation to use. To use ES6 would require users to add a transpilation step. Why should you require this extra overhead? When's the last time you saw react components distributed without requiring a build step?

That being said, ES6 code works well with Polymer. I use both in my projects. It will work much better when the proposed changes to the custom elements spec are available.

Comment: I'm confused - it seems that the Polymer Elements don't use ES6, yet the Polymer CLI generates ES6 custom elements (`class X extends Polymer.element{ ... }`). Should I change it to use ES5 in my custom components for maximum browser support?